# Getting runtime exception while converting long to binary and then concatenated binary String to long

Tags: java, string, binary, long-integer

I was trying this question on HackerEarth platform
You are given a number n. Find the decimal value of the number formed by concatenation of binary representation of the first n positive integer.

Sample Input
3

Sample OutPut
27 (1: 1, 2: 10, 3: 11, result: 11011)

My Solution:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        long n = Long.parseLong(br.readLine().trim());

        long out_ = FindBigNum(n);
        wr.println(out_);
        wr.close();
        br.close();
    }

    static long FindBigNum(long n) {
        // Write your code here
        String str = "";
        for (long i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
            str += Long.toBinaryString(i);
        }
        return Long.parseLong(str, 2);
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest efficient way to do this?

Comment: Don't *explain* the code, *show* the code.

Comment: Like Andreas said, you're on the right track, but I am pretty sure there is a bug in your code.

Comment: More efficient solution: Use `<<` bit-shift operator, and optionally the [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-) method, but it can be done without that method.

Comment: @Andreas I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, for a more efficient solution, use `<<` bit-shift operator, and the [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-) method:

```java
static long binaryConcatRange(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n > 17)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range (0-17): " + n);
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int bitLen = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
        result = (result << bitLen) | i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For a potentially<sup>1</sup> even more efficient solution, it can be done without the `numberOfLeadingZeros()` method:

```java
static long binaryConcatRange(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n > 17)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range (0-17): " + n);
    long result = 0;
    for (int bitLen = 0, nextLenAt = 1, i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i == nextLenAt) {
            bitLen++;
            nextLenAt <<= 1;
        }
        result = (result << bitLen) | i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

<sup>*1) Method `numberOfLeadingZeros()` is annotated with `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`, so it may be super-fast using a native solution, which means that this Java code alternative might not be faster.*</sup>

*Test*

```java
for (int n = 0; n < 18; n++)
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", n, binaryConcatRange(n));
```

*Output*

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 6
3: 27
4: 220
5: 1765
6: 14126
7: 113015
8: 1808248
9: 28931977
10: 462911642
11: 7406586283
12: 118505380540
13: 1896086088653
14: 30337377418462
15: 485398038695407
16: 15532737238253040
17: 497047591624097297
```

---

To support values of `n` greater than 17, return type must be changed to a `BigInteger`:

```java
static BigInteger binaryConcatRange(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range: " + n);
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int bitLen = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
        result = result.shiftLeft(bitLen).or(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Test*

```java
for (int n = 18; n < 32; n++)
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", n, binaryConcatRange(n));
for (int n = 32; n <= 256; n *= 2)
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", n, binaryConcatRange(n));
```

*Output*

```
18: 15905522931971113522
19: 508976733823075632723
20: 16287255482338420247156
21: 521192175434829447909013
22: 16678149613914542333088438
23: 533700787645265354658830039
24: 17078425204648491349082561272
25: 546509606548751723170641960729
26: 17488307409560055141460542743354
27: 559625837105921764526737367787355
28: 17908026787389496464855595769195388
29: 573056857196463886875379064614252445
30: 18337819430286844380012130067656078270
31: 586810221769179020160388162164994504671
32: 37555854193227457290264842378559648298976
64: 471483835060474447584605138071473227083738554722043752192205889593231757234798071314332600270577600
128: 685385418402711161486992779215452480197156956593160845028648293349782283935659509581295718147533155031188929619519081596427609304635849304708531968190976802229890594798789934166770532152593884743090295308624351511929798643557538430848
256: 246422532279457970240939131862416256957912100676567284022182930350788567839691502682935548861928505318417306075544389639956672552326580169008528080129830322429712508593083839769096175727133924908330823876506697567963272081220317027757129623022363719594776044926884107531078136465754901556922215598679264299348040837049670711753684521748473384638643859758271742330378295219493243936419532611365679896772551640598210176805609455785828091793688653809020045393677303410807761070390084298154799431073337833749694111293934995919750974732669988765440
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder to contain the binary number.

To append the bits of the next number, use a mask of the highest one bit
and AND the value with the mask, shifting the mask right 1 bit until 0.

```
Say v = 1100
highest 1 bit is 1000
```

- `v & 1000 = 1` so append a `1`
- `v & 0100 = 1` so append a `1`
- `v & 0010 = 0` so append a `0`
- `v & 0001 = 0` so append a `0`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    appendBinary(sb, i);
    System.out.println(i + " : "
            + new BigInteger(sb.toString(), 2));
}
}
    
public static StringBuilder appendBinary(StringBuilder sb, int v) {
    int mask = Integer.highestOneBit(v);
    while (mask != 0) {
        char bit = ((v & mask) == 0) ? '0' : '1';
        sb.append(bit);
        // In case v is negative.  Then mask will be negative.
        // So shift accordingly.
        mask >>>= 1;
    }
    // Convenience return.
    // Same object as provided.
    return sb;
}
```

Prints

```
1 : 1
2 : 6
3 : 27
4 : 220
5 : 1765
6 : 14126
7 : 113015
8 : 1808248
9 : 28931977
10 : 462911642
11 : 7406586283
12 : 118505380540
13 : 1896086088653
14 : 30337377418462
```